# How do i write Xquery for below XML

Tags: xml, xquery

```
<root>
        <StatementDetail>  
                <PolicyNo>POL-01</PolicyNo>
                <name>john</name>
                <InstallmentNo>0</InstallmentNo>  
                <NetAmount>250.00</NetAmount>   
                <NetAmountTotal>250.00</>
                <AmountTotal>300.00</AmountTotal>
        </StatementDetail>
        <StatementDetail>  
                <PolicyNo>POL-01</PolicyNo>
                <name>john</name>  
                <InstallmentNo>1</InstallmentNo>  
                <NetAmount>50.00</NetAmount>  
                <NetAmountTotal>50.00</NetAmountTotal>
                <AmountTotal>300.00</AmountTotal>
        </StatementDetail>
        <StatementDetail>  
                <PolicyNo>POL-02</PolicyNo>
                <name>ravi</name>  
                <InstallmentNo>0</InstallmentNo>  
                <NetAmount>270.00</NetAmount>
                <NetAmountTotal>500.00</NetAmountTotal>
                <AmountTotal>500.00</AmountTotal>                       
        </StatementDetail>  
        <StatementDetail>  
                <PolicyNo>POL-02</PolicyNo>
                <name>ravi</name>
                <InstallmentNo>0</InstallmentNo>    
                <NetAmount>230.00</NetAmount>
                <NetAmountTotal>500.00</NetAmountTotal>
                <AmountTotal>500.00</AmountTotal>
        </StatementDetail>
        </root>
        };
```

My Code:

```
  #xquery(for $x in /root/StatementDetail
  let $PolicyNo := fn:upper-case($x/PolicyNo)
  let $Name := $x/Name
  let $InstNo := $x/InstallmentNo
  let $NetAmt := $x/NetAmount
  let $NetAmtTot := $x/NetAmountTotal
  let $AmtTot := $x/AmountTotal
  return <AgencyStatementDetail>
                <PolicyNo>{$PolicyNo}</PolicyNo>
                <Name>{$Name}</Name>
                <InstallmentNo>{$InstNo}</InstallmentNo>
                <NetAmount>{$NetAmt}</NetAmount>
                <NetAmountTotal>{$NetAmtTot}</NetAmountTotal>
                <AmountTotal>{$AmtTot}</AmountTotal>
        </AgencyStatementDetail>)
```

Output Comes like :

```
Policy      Name    InstNo  Amount
    
POL-01      John    0       250
                    Total   250
                    1        50
                    Total   50
Total POL-01                300
   
 POL-02      Ravi    0       270
                    Total   270
                     0       230
                    Total   500
Total POL-02                500
```

And Output Needed like :
POL-02      Ravi     0      270
0      230
Total    500
Total POL-02                500

I want output like based on instNo it should not repeat again total should appears only once.how will i perform this to get such output. Please help writing XQuery.

Comment: Output needed not comes in tabular format please consider it

Comment: Please always provide your XQuery implementation (in the question or as tag) and the version of both your processor and the XQuery variant, you are working with. Thanks.